How to convert temporary download links, which after some time expire, to permanent download links?
i need to download so many huge files from a website via IDM.
I copy and paste links in the morning so i can download them with IDM at night, but the problem is the links are temporary and expire after some time. Is there a website or any way to change them into permanent download links, that never expire?
(I can only copy the links in the morning in case you are wondering)
Thanks in advance.
I searched for hours and found nothing.
The only related question i found was another person in stackoverflow, however nobody has answered him.
I tried to do it with FDM and open source file managers (as the other person had said) but they didn't do the trick.

To turn it into permanent you need to host that file (or find someone host it for you).You can rent a server and launching a http web server and store the permanent file in the webroot.
But anyway you need to be able to download it to somewhere first,if the original file is like "My link is expiring in 10 minutes but the file is 100gb large and I will limit the maximum download speed to 100kbps"then this will be a blame-service-provider moment.
